# Artemis: AMQ222210: Storage usage is beyond max-disk-usage. System will start blocking producers

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm sending a message from Application A to Artemis but I'm getting this error from Application A:

```
AMQ212054: Destination address=my-service is blocked. If the system is configured to block make sure you consume messages on this configuration.
```

Looking at the logs of artemis starting up this is what I see which I believe is the cause:

```
AMQ222210: Storage usage is beyond max-disk-usage. System will start blocking producers
```

I've looked at the documentation [here](https://github.com/vromero/activemq-artemis-docker) and found nothing that could help. Also have logged into the running container and changed the 'max-disk-usage' to 100 as per my google research and so far nothing has helped.

I'm running artemis using the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -e ARTEMIS_USERNAME=artemis -e ARTEMIS_PASSWORD=artemis -p 8161:8161 -p 61616:61616 vromero/activemq-artemis
```

Any help is appreciated~ Thank you

Comment: Did you restart the broker after you changed the `max-disk-usage`?  You'll need to restart it to pick up the change.

Comment: It automatically restarts when the configurations are changed. It's an intermittent issue it seems to have fixed itself now.

Comment: What automatically restarts the broker when broker.xml is changed?  Is that a docker thing?  As far as the broker itself goes, it will automatically pick up *some* changes in broker.xml, but I don't believe `max-disk-usage` is one of them.

Answer (score 6):

You are receiving this message because you computer's disk space is over 90% full and Artemis blocks producers once this happens. To solve your problem you can either:

1. Clear up disk space on your computer so that it is below 90% .
2. Increase how full your disk can be before Artimes blocks producers. To do this you need to modify the broker configuration file which is located at:

```
path-to-broker\artemis\etc\broker.xml
```

In this file, there is a tag labeled `max-disk-usage` which is by default set to `90`. Simply increase this to `100` (or whatever value you feel comfortable with).

Note that the reason Artemis configures your brokers to start blocking producers once you computer's disk space usage reaches 90% and above is to prevent potentially using up all of your disk space in the case of message back log.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded a different version and this issue hasn't occurred anymore.